# JHipster - Generate gateway from existing AWS microservice

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to generate a Gateway from an existing microservice hosted in AWS (I also have it on my local machine).  According to the [JHipster Doing Microservices](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) under the 'Creating Microservices' section, it states: "If you choose to generate the entity from a microservice, you will need to enter the path to this microservice on your local computer, and then JHipster will generate the front-end code on the gateway."

To me this means if I can generate an entity from a microservice, I should be able to generate the Gateway from the generated entity.

Does anyone know the commands, or setup steps, or have a guide on how to do such a thing?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your understanding is correct.
Assuming you already have generated a microservice app with `Foo` entity.

1. Generate a gateway using `yo jhipster`
2. In gateway folder, run `yo jhipster:entity Foo`. Choose to generate the entity from a microservice, enter the path to this microservice on your local computer, and then JHipster will generate the front-end code on the gateway according to the definition of the entity in the service  `.jhipster/Foo.json`

Comment: I see that is the key there.  "Assuming you have generated a microservice app ..."  I was initially trying to do it from a microservice I created manually, not one that is generated.

When I tried to run `yo jhipster:entitiy <path-to-microservice-root>` it was complaining that the .jhipster directory wasn't found.  I'm assuming the front-end is generated from the `.json` files that are found in there.

Comment: Correct, there's no magic here, JHipster only knows about entities that were created by Jhipster but even if you were writing json entity files manually you'll have to modify your service to make it an eureka client and be comapaible with authentication on gateway